# Maximum tenant supported in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does anyone know what the maximum tenant is supported in WSO2 Identity Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally there is no maximum limit. Tenant Id is stored as a int value. Therefore in theory you should be able to create upto `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
I did some load test for tenant creation with WSO2 IS and was able to create about 20000 tenants without any issue.